# How to check if a string contains a sequence of equal symbols, which are are equal to another sequence of symbols in the same string? (JAVA)

Tags: java, string, sequence, string-comparison

For example I have String

`Cash$$$$$$Ca$$$$$$sh`

With left side: `Cash$$$$$$` and right side: `Ca$$$$$$sh`

I want to implement a method which returns true if the left side contains sequence, of equal characters, which is equal to the sequence in the right side. Their values must be the same and so as their length.
This example returns true.

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash First half of the string is the left part and the other half is the right substring if you'd like to call it.

Comment: For example the string length is equal to 20. Left is the first 10 characters. And right is the other 10 characters.

Comment: Please be more specific. Why does the above example return true?  What about `abcdea`?  The 'a' and 'c' each could be considered a sequence of 1.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to write a method.

```
      System.out.println(checkString("Cash$$$$$$Ca$$$$$$sh")); //false
      System.out.println(checkString("Cash$$$$$$Cash$$$$$$")); //true
      System.out.println(checkString("abcdabc")); // false
      System.out.println(checkString("abcabc")); // true;

   public static boolean checkString(String str) {
      // odd length of strings can't have equals halves.
      if (str.length() % 2 == 1) {
         return false;
      }
      int mid = str.length()/2;
      for (char c : str.substring(0,mid).toCharArray()) {
         if (c != str.charAt(mid++)) {
            return false;
         }
      }
      return true;
   }
```